# VBA - Split cell values and put it into the row below

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a code that would split the cells of the last row after ":" as shown below:

Before

[image]

After

[image]

So far splitting data looks like this - but it only works for the first cell:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet3")
Dim fullstring As String, colonposition As Integer, j As Integer, LastRow As Long, FirstRow As Long
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For j = 1 To 3
    fullstring = Cells(lRow, lCol).Value
    colonposition = InStr(fullstring, ":")
    Cells(lRow, j).Value = Left(fullstring, colonposition - 1)
    lRow = lRow + 1
    Cells(lRow, j).Value = Mid(fullstring, colonposition + 1)
    Next

End Sub
```

I have found a similar problematic (with answer) [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/736878-visual-basic-applications-split-cell-values-put-into-row-below.html) but can't manage to apply it ONLY to the last row

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case some people are interested in the answers to the discussion with @Ondrej, here are two codes, the first is static and the second is dynamic:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim actualRange As Range
For Each actualRange In ws.Range(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlToRight))
If InStr(Trim(actualRange), ":") > 0 Then
actualRange.Offset(1, 0).Value = Split(actualRange.Value, ":")(1)
actualRange.Offset(0, 0).Value = Split(actualRange.Value, ":")(0)

End If
Next
End Sub
```

&

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim actualRange As Range
Dim tmpString As String
For Each actualRange In ws.Range(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlToRight))
tmpString = actualRange.Value
If InStr(Trim(tmpString), ":") > 0 Then
actualRange.Offset(0, 0).Value = Split(tmpString, ":")(0)

actualRange.Offset(1, 0).Value = Split(tmpString, ":")(1)

End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using Range method with for each statement, like following:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet3")
    Dim actualRange As Range
    For Each actualRange In ws.Range(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).End(xlToRight))
        actualRange.Offset(-1, 0).Value = Split(actualRange.Value, ":")(0)
        actualRange.Offset(0, 0).Value = Split(actualRange.Value, ":")(1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it looked good on a sample of my data, however it seems to be inverted: the first half should remain in the cell and the second half should go in the cell below. How would you go about to tweak it?

Comment: Thanks! Any idea as to why when I try to run it I sometimes get 'subscript out of range'?

Comment: You have to check whether the cell value contains delimiter, in this case ":". Just check it with InStr and if returned value is greater than -1.

Comment: Thanks. FYI (and if it can help others) after `For Each`, I included `If InStr(Trim(actualRange), ":") > 0 Then` and the rest of your code

Comment: last question, I promise: the first half of the split moves one row above (instead of staying in the same row) and the second half stays in the same row. How would you do the opposite: leave the first half in the same row and move the second half to the row below?

Comment: You have to change the code like this:

actualRange.Offset(0, 0).Value = Split(actualRange.Value, ":")(0)

actualRange.Offset(1, 0).Value = Split(actualRange.Value, ":")(1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117317/discussion-between-pdx-and-ondrej-holman).